# Paypal payment REST API execute process using guzzle

Tags: php, rest, curl, paypal, guzzle

I want to ask about paypal REST execute process. As defined in the documentation,

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/payment_id/execute/ \\
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \\
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \\
  -d '{
  "payer_id": "payer_id"
}'
```

the code is for **curl** version which I want to change to **guzzle** version but am bit confused about **"Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"**

Is **"Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"** is placed on header config like **"Content-Type:application/json"**?

Because I always get error 500 from Paypal sandbox server and when I tried to access API Call history page on Paypal sandbox dashboard it always show "Something went wrong fetching sandbox API calls. Try again."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently the best option to implement `Bearer` authentication is to add a header:

```
$response = $client->post(
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/payment_id/execute/',
    [
        'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer #your_token#'],
        'json' => ['payer_id' => '#your_payer_id#'],
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hi about this line `['payer_id' => '#your_payer_id#']` why is this included in `'json'` and not in  data?

Comment: `json` is just a shortcut for `data` combined with `json_encode()` and `Content-Type` header. [Read in the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).

Comment: thanks for explanation, but my request still return error from paypal sandbox. after some search i found paypal php sdk and decided to use that, instead create request manually using guzzle  :)